# Woocommerce - Validation on cart page

Tags: wordpress, validation, woocommerce, shopping-cart, woocommerce-theming

I have a custom filed for specific shipping methods (see screenshot).

Is there a hook/action to validate this field **before** proceeding the checkout. When I set the field to `required` the validation will fire at the checkout page but I want it at the **cart** page.

[image]

Validation:

```php
//Validate the custom selection field
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'carrier_company_checkout_validation');
function carrier_company_checkout_validation() {
    Load settings and convert them in variables
    extract( custom_field_settings() );

    if(  isset( $_POST[$field_id] ) && empty( $_POST[$field_id] ) )
        wc_add_notice(
            sprintf( __("Please select a %s as it is a required field.","woocommerce"),
            '<strong>' . $label_name . '</strong>'
        ), "error" );
}
```

** **UPDATE:** **

like @LoicTheAztec mentioned here the complete code.

Everything is working fine. The custom input value from cart will be shown on checkout and saved in the DB after order confirmation. But I don't know where I have to put the validation on the cart page when the custom input is empty because everything on cart is on ajax.

```php
    // ##########################################
    // Add custom fields to a specific selected shipping method
    // ##########################################
    // Custom function that handle your settings
      function delivery_date_settings(){
        return array(
            'field_id'         => 'delivery_date', // Field Id
            'field_type'       => 'text', // Field type
            'field_label'      => 'label text', // Leave empty value if the first option has a text (see below).
            'label_name'       => __("Lieferdatum","woocommerce"), // for validation and as meta key for orders
        );
      }
    
    
      
      // Display the custom checkout field
      add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'carrier_company_custom_select_field', 20, 2 );
      function carrier_company_custom_select_field( $method, $index ) {
          
          if( $method->id == 'flat_rate:2' || $method->id == 'free_shipping:1') {
            extract( delivery_date_settings() ); // Load settings and convert them in variables
      
            $chosen  = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods'); // The chosen methods
            $value   = WC()->session->get($field_id);
            $value   = WC()->session->__isset($field_id) ? $value : WC()->checkout->get_value('_'.$field_id);
            $options = array(); // Initializing
        
            $chosen_method_id = WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $index ];
    
            if($chosen_method_id == 'flat_rate:2' || $method->id == 'free_shipping:1' ){                
              echo '<div class="custom-date-field">';
        
              woocommerce_form_field( $field_id, array(
                  'type'     => $field_type,
                  'label'    => $field_label, // Not required if the first option has a text.
                  'class'    => array('form-row-wide datepicker ' . $field_id . '-' . $field_type ),
                  'required' => false,
              ), $value );
      
              echo '</div>';
                  // Jquery: Enable the Datepicker
                ?>
                <script language="javascript">
                jQuery( function($){
                    $('.datepicker input').datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', // ISO formatting date
                    });
                });
                </script>
                <?php
            }
          }
    
    
    
    
    
      }
      
      // jQuery code (client side) - Ajax sender 
      add_action( 'wp_footer', 'carrier_company_script_js' );
      function carrier_company_script_js() {
          // Only cart & checkout pages
          if( is_cart() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ):
      
          // Load settings and convert them in variables
          extract( lieferdatum_settings() );
      
          $js_variable = is_cart() ? 'wc_cart_params' : 'wc_checkout_params';
      
          // jQuery Ajax code
          ?>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery( function($){
              if (typeof <?php echo $js_variable; ?> === 'undefined')
                  return false;
      
              $(document.body).on( 'change', 'input#<?php echo $field_id; ?>', function(){
                  var value = $(this).val();
                  $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: <?php echo $js_variable; ?>.ajax_url,
                      data: {
                          'action': 'delivery_date',
                          'value': value
                      },
                      success: function (result) {
                          console.log(result); // Only for testing (to be removed)
                      }
                  });
              });
          });
          </script>
          <?php
          endif;
      }
      
      // The Wordpress Ajax PHP receiver
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_delivery_date', 'set_carrier_company_name' );
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_delivery_date', 'set_carrier_company_name' );
      function set_carrier_company_name() {
          if ( isset($_POST['value']) ){
              // Load settings and convert them in variables
              extract( delivery_date_settings() );
      
              if( empty($_POST['value']) ) {
                  $value = 0;
                  $label = 'Empty';
              } else {
                  $value = $label = esc_attr( $_POST['value'] );
              }
      
              // Update session variable
              WC()->session->set( $field_id, $value );
      
              // Send back the data to javascript (json encoded)
              echo $label;
              die();
          }
      }
      
      
      
      // Save custom field as order meta data
      add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_carrier_company_as_order_meta', 30, 1 );
      function save_carrier_company_as_order_meta( $order ) {
        // Load settings and convert them in variables
        extract( delivery_date_settings() );
      
        if( isset( $_POST[$field_id] ) && ! empty( $_POST[$field_id] ) ) {
            $order->update_meta_data( '_'.$field_id, esc_attr($_POST[$field_id]) );
            WC()->session->__unset( $field_id ); // remove session variable
        }
      }
      
      // Display custom field in admin order pages
      add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'admin_order_display_carrier_company', 30, 1 );
      function admin_order_display_carrier_company( $order ) {
          // Load settings and convert them in variables
          extract( delivery_date_settings() );
      
          $carrier = $order->get_meta( '_'.$field_id ); // Get carrier company
      
          if( ! empty($carrier) ) {
              // Display
              echo '<p><strong>' . $label_name . '</strong>: ' . $carrier . '</p>';
          }
      }
      
      // Display carrier company after shipping line everywhere (orders and emails)
      add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'display_carrier_company_on_order_item_totals', 1000, 3 );
      function display_carrier_company_on_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
          // Load settings and convert them in variables
          extract( delivery_date_settings() );
      
          $carrier = $order->get_meta( '_'.$field_id ); // Get carrier company
      
          if( ! empty($carrier) ) {
              $new_total_rows = [];
      
              // Loop through order total rows
              foreach( $total_rows as $key => $values ) {
                  $new_total_rows[$key] = $values;
                  
                  // Inserting the carrier company under shipping method
                  if( $key === 'shipping' ) {
                      $new_total_rows[$field_id] = array(
                          'label' => $label_name,
                          'value' => $carrier,
                      );
                  }
              }
              return $new_total_rows;
          }
          return $total_rows;
      }
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks for the advice, I am new at woocommerce and also php. here you can find the complete code for the custom field on the cart page. could you please take a look at the code and tell me where I have to add the validation for the ajax part? thanks a lot!!!!
https://gist.github.com/larzknoke/0d340bf49e3f38eaa78c88f01242b33c

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thx a lot because I don't get any further with this problem.... :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the hook you're looking for is `woocommerce_check_cart_items`, that's the one that validates the cart items before proceeding to checkout.

I'm not 100% sure whether you'll be able to get the field in the same way using `$_POST` but it's worth a go.